# Induced voltage as a difference of potentials on a ring

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, potential, voltage, electromagnetic-induction

If you put a ring (*Picture 1*) of wire into changing magnetic field, the process called magnetic induction creates induced voltage. Voltage is by definition (*Definition 2*) the difference in electric potential between two points. But where exactly on a ring are this two points of mentioned electric potential? If they were stationary, it would not be possible to measure induced current in the looped piece of wire, but we can absolutly do that. So my question is... What is induced voltage on a ring? Where are this two points of electric potential? Does the definiton of voltage make any sanse in this case?

""Voltage, electric potential difference, electromotive force (emf), electric pressure or electric tension is the difference in electric potential between two points"" (*Definiton 2*; from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage)

[image: Picture 1]
*Picture 1*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) "Voltage is by definition (Definition 2) the difference in electric potential between two points." No, you are defining potential difference, a concept that can't be usefully applied to this situation.

(b) If there is a potential difference between two points A and B then a test charge taken from one point to the other will have work done on it by an electric field of an amount independent of the path taken from A to B. This is clearly not the case here. If you choose any two points on the ring, positive work will be done on the test charge if you take it from A to B in one sense round the ring, and negative work if you take it in the other sense. The concept of electric potential is inapplicable.

(c) The electric field generated in the ring if we continuously increase or decrease the magnetic flux linked with the ring is, we say, a non-conservative field. It isn't like the  electric field due to static charges, which *is* a conservative field, to which we can apply the concepts of potential and potential difference.

(d) If the ring were made of metal and had a gap in it, then we *would* be able to talk about the potential difference between the cut ends. This is because mobile charges are urged round the ring by the induced electric field so one end gets a positive charge and the other a negative. These (essentially static) charges give rise to a conservative electric field.

(e) Back to 'voltage'. This is a more general term meaning work done per unit charge on a test charge. So we can talk about the voltage induced in the ring, meaning the line integral of the electric field strength as we go once round the ring. Specifically, this is the *emf* induced in the ring.

Answer (score 2):

Once $\partial {\bf B}/{\partial t}\ne 0$ the  electric field cannot be written as $-\nabla V$ with a single valued $V$, so there is no "potential."   The idea of an electric potential is a concept from electrostatics.

Indeed if you take a voltmeter and try to read a potential difference between two points on the ring the reading will depend on how you dispose the leads from the probes to the meter. This is because there will be a changing flux in the loop made of the bit of ring between the probes, the leads and the meter.

Answer (score 1):

Magnitude of the voltage induced in the Conductor also depends upon the angle between the magnetic field lines and the conductor.

Changing magnetic field lines will make different angles with each point on the rings and therefore will cause different voltages at different points and that will make the current flow in the ring.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of electric potential goes out the window for changing magnetic fields, as
$$\nabla\times\mathbf{E}=-\frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t} \neq \mathbf{0},$$
or, equivalently, the line integral of the electric field is dependent on the path taken. This means that the potential difference between two points is no longer uniquely defined, as it depends on the path taken.

We must therefore turn to a new concept: emf. The emf associated with a loop $C$ is the line integral around $C$ of the force per unit charge. In electromagnetism,
$$\mathcal{E} = \oint_{C}{(\mathbf{E}+\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{B})\cdot\,d\mathbf{l}},$$
where $\mathbf{v}$ denotes the velocity of the charges as they move around the loop. The flux rule says that the emf induced in any loop is the negative time rate of change of the flux of the magnetic field through a surface bounded by the loop:
$$\mathcal{E}=-\frac{d\Phi_B}{dt}.$$
This notion of emf has none of the problems that you discussed. Only the loop as a whole, not two particular points in the loop, factors into the calculation.

Summary:

- The electric potential is **not** well-defined when the magnetic field is changing. The potential is only useful in electro*static* situations.
- The emf associated with a loop is the line integral around the loop of the force per unit charge. This concept frees us to consider the entire loop instead of two points on it.

Comment: > *"potential difference between two points is no longer uniquely defined, as it depends on the path taken."* Potential difference can still be uniquely defined based on the conservative part of electric field. This is useful in AC circuits.

Comment: $\mathbf v$ in that formula is not velocity of the mobile charges, but velocity of the conductor.

Answer (score 0):

Voltage and potential difference between two points are very different concepts. The electric field has two contributions. The conservative part, associated with electric charge accumulations (whose integration between two points gives place to the potential difference and do not exist in this problem) and the non-conservative contribution or the induction component, associated with the time derivative of the vector potential. The voltage between two points corresponds to the sum of the two line integrals between those points. The first one is independent of the chosen path while the second one depends.
In this problem, we have a conducting and EQUIPOTENTIAL loop while a current flows on it; we can suposse current in the clockwise direction. A voltmeter connected between the top (positive terminal) and the bottom (negative terminal) of the loop will read a positive voltage if the wires of the voltmeter are on the right hand side and out of the loop area. However, it will read a negative voltage if the wires of the voltmeter are on the left hand side and also out of the loop area. Moreover, if the wires form a rectilinear path between the top and the bottom points, the voltmeter will mark zero, but if the wires do not form a rectilinear path between these points the voltmeter will no longer read zero.